# Multi-INSERT with unchangeable param

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to INSERT multiple values with one from DB that unchangable?
I thought about WITH but without success:

```
WITH t as (SELECT date_trunc('hour', NOW())) 
INSERT INTO my_table(ID, TIME) VALUES (1,t),(2,t);
```

Comment: Try `WITH t as (SELECT date_trunc('hour', NOW()) hour_t) INSERT INTO my_table(ID, TIME) VALUES (1,t.hour_t),(2,t.hour_t);`

Comment: @Politank-Z: no, won't work. You can't reference a table like that in the `values` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the CTE, just use a plain SELECT as the source for the insert:

```
insert into my_table (id, time)
select i, date_trunc('hour', NOW())
from generate_series(1,2) i;
```

If you really want the CTE, you need to select from it in the values clause:

```
WITH t as (
   SELECT date_trunc('hour', NOW()) hour_t
) 
INSERT INTO my_table(ID, TIME) 
VALUES 
(1, (select hour_t from t)),
(2, (select hour_t from t));
```